# Is it possible to only extract text from a PDF file for free?

Tags: pdf

Even if I download books in mobi or epub format for my Kindle, I’ve noticed that files with lots of images/graphs disrupt the formatting.

Is there a way to delete all the images from a PDF file for free?

Comment: Yes but easier to do from a epub or mobi The text remaining will be less corrupted then if you got it from a pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.
The program is called Calibre. There is even command line processing support which I have used to batch process multiple pdf files' 'extraction'. By adjusting the parameters, one can extract standard text. Of course, some pdf files are an assembly of images and contain no actual text. But give this 'a shot' :)

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier IMHO to use command-line tools for that. Many tools which allowed that were around for years, but my favourite tool for converting text from pdf is now `ebook-convert`. It not only allows outputting text characters from a pdf file, but also intelligently edits the text to avoid unncessary line breaks etc. Which is necessary as pdf is a presentation format not designed to preserve text in a form allowing further processing. `ebook-convert` is available on linux. Basic invocation is quite simple:

```
ebook-convert input.pdf output.txt
```

Hovever, at the very least, you will probably want:

```
ebook-convert input.pdf output.txt --enable-heuristics
```

It has plenty of other options to test.